# Get string between first open parentheses and last close parentheses

Tags: php, str-replace, explode

I need to get the string between the position of the first parenthesis and the position of the last parenthesis, to then make a str_replace between those parentheses, finally an explode to get the fields separated by commas

something like this:

```
$string = field1,field2,(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) as field3,field4;
```

**The function to call has to get this part of the string. (if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) then:**

```
$string_btwn_parenthesis = [(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_))]; <- obtained by function
```

*I want to get this **-->**(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_))**<--**

not **-->**(if(isnull(table.id_)**<--**,1,table.id_))*

```
$string_replaced = str_replace($string_btwn_parenthesis," ",$string);

$arrayfields = explode(",",$string_replaced);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the regex `(\(.*\))` do just that?

Comment: use a regex to do this

Comment: would regex be useful for dinamic strings ?

Comment: @apokryfos what regex I need if I have to get within first parenthesis and the field alias?
$string = field1,field2,(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) as field3,field4;
$string_btwn_parenthesis = (if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) AS;

Comment: `/(\(.*\) as .*?)[;,]/i` will probably work but you're heading down the slippery slope of slowly writing a MySQL parser. Perhaps take a step back?

Comment: @apokryfos this is what I really want: $position= strpos($sql,"from",0); $sql_fields= substr($sql,0 ,$position); $sql_fields = substr($sql_fields ,7); to cut from "SELECT field1" so I have the fields then I need explode it to get the fields in array $array_fields = explode(",",$sql_fields); the problem begins when I'm getting concat fields or any condition like this field1,field2,(if(isnull(table.id_),1,table.id_)) as field3,field4;